# Docker compose watch with "sync" action giving error "file exists". "rebuild" works OK

Tags: django, docker-compose

I am trying to configure Django project with `docker compose watch` to sync code changes into the containerized Django app.

The compose file is as follows:

```yaml
include:
  - compose-db-dev.yaml
services:
  webapp:
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.dev
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: .
          target: /app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

With the action as "sync" I get the following error:

```
Syncing webapp after changes were detected:
  - /home/jb/myapp/main/views.py
itar: app/main/views.py: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
WARN[0023] Error handling changed files for service webapp: 1 error occurred:
        * copying files to 47b692a96cf0e7b8edd3922f27aaa05fd63d511176cfe1362126828a28d9f030: exit code 2
```

This error does not occur with the watch action set to `rebuild`. It works fine, updating the app. However it takes several seconds to rebuild the image and is not the ideal workflow resource wise.

AFAIK changing a view in a Django app should NOT require a "rebuild" of the service, so I think the sync action is preferrable. It is expected that the "file exists" (sync is of existing files), so why do I get this error?

Comment: I can replicate the same problem using an even simpler `compose.yml` file, as mine contains neither `include` nor `depends_on` sections.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in compose watch, for a workaround you need to run your container as root, bug issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11304

So instead off `USER myappuser` simply use `USER root`, but you are better off making a "dev" stage in the Dockerfile and use root only in it so your "prod" stage that would run in production, can still use the nonroot "appuser".

**UPDATE:** Looks like the problem is that compose watch tries to copy the files with wrong file permissions, so you need to use chown in your COPY command in the Dockerfile. Also as this is my first ever python project, I couldn't make live reload work with gunicorn, only with python dev server, so the prod stage uses gunicorn, the dev stage uses python dev server as the CMD but **it is not needed to do USER root in any of the stages** if you do `COPY --chown=appuser:appuser ./mydjangoapi .`. I updated the Dockerfile below.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# you need the previous first line as it is, to use the newest and greatest Dockerfile features
# https://docs.docker.com/build/dockerfile/frontend/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.12
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as prod

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser ./mydjangoapi .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD gunicorn mydjangoapi.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000

FROM prod as dev

# use python dev server that uses live reload, configured in settings.py with USE_LIVERELOAD = True
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Also to reflect this in compose.yaml you need to set `target: dev` for the build setting:

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./mydjangoapi
          target: /app
```

Comment: Hey @zsolt thanks for your answer. I will try to apply your sugeestions and confirm if it solved for me.